# JSON deserialize if the Field is missing in the JSON object , Set the Field in a wrapper class to NULL

Tags: json, api, serialization, salesforce, apex

```
JSON Object 
 {
    x = 'String1'

}
```

Consider this scenario if the JSON object is passing only one value I want to set the other value to NULL Which in this case is **Y**

```
 public with sharing class SerializeObject{
        public String x {get;set;}
        public String y {get;set;}
 }
```

Function that Serialize

```
 public SerializeObject SerializeObjectJSON(String json){
    return (SerializeObject ) System.JSON.deserialize(json.replace('""','null'), SerializeObject.class);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "object" is not valid JSON. I don't know what you're trying to do but you have some serious issues with data source, not with Apex. If you fix your syntax errors - other variable will be null out of the box.

```
public with sharing class SerializeObject{
        public String x {get;set;}
        public String y {get;set;}
}

String s = '{"x" : "String 1"}';

SerializeObject so = (SerializeObject) JSON.deserialize(s, SerializeObject.class);
System.debug(so.x); // String 1
System.debug(so.y); // null
```